# Dynamically Animating Hue Shift on Canvas Image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, colors, hue

I'm still relatively new to working with the canvas tag. What I've done so far is draw an image to the canvas. My goal is to have a fake night/day animation that cycles repeatedly.

I've exhausted quite a few different avenues (SVG, CSS3 filters, etc) and think that canvas pixel manipulation is the best route in my case. I'm trying to:

1. Loop through all pixels in the image
2. Select a certain color range
3. Adjust to new color
4. Update the canvas

Here's the code I have so far:

```
function gameLoop(){
        requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);        

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // LOOP PIXEL DATA - PIXEL'S RGBA IS STORED IN SEQUENTIAL ARRAYS
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i+=4){
            red=data[i+0];
            green=data[i+1];
            blue=data[i+2];
            alpha=data[i+3];

            // GET HUE BY CONVERTING TO HSL
            var hsl=rgbToHsl(red, green, blue);
            var hue=hsl.h*360;

            // CHANGE SET COLORRANGE TO NEW COLORSHIFT
            if(hue>colorRangeStart && hue<colorRangeEnd){
                var newRgb=hslToRgb(hsl.h+colorShift, hsl.s, hsl.l);
                data[i+0]=newRgb.r;
                data[i+1]=newRgb.g;
                data[i+2]=newRgb.b;
                data[i+3]=255;
            };
        };

        // UPDATE CANVAS
        ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);        
    };
```

The code works and selects a hue ranges and shifts it once, but is incredibly laggy. The canvas dimensions are roughly 500x1024.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to improve performance?
2. Is there a better way to perform a defined hue shift animation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to do this real-time using high quality HSL conversion. Been there done that, so I came up with a quantized approach which allow you to do this in real-time.

You can find the solution here (GPL3.0 licensed):
https://github.com/epistemex/FastHSL2RGB

Example of usage can be found here (MIT license) incl. demo:
https://github.com/epistemex/HueWheel

Apologies for referencing my own solutions here, but the inner workings (the how to's) is too extensive to present in a simple form here and both of these are free to use for anything..

The key points are in any case:

- Quantize the range you want to use (don't use full 360 degrees and not floating points for lightness etc.)
- Cache the values in a 3D array (initial setup using web workers or use rough values)
- Quantize the input values so they fit in the range of the inner 3D array
- Process the bitmap using these values

It is not accurate but good enough for animations (or previews which is what I wrote it for).

There are other techniques such as pre-caching the complete processed bitmap for key positions, then interpolate the colors between those instead. This, of course, requires much more memory but is a fast way.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This looks very promising - giving it a shot now. :D

Comment: Great work - exactly what I was need and makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to reupload the full source to those projects, as the github repository seems to be not the same as when this was written.